# getting json property that needs another http request

Tags: html, angularjs, json

Hi its kinda long to explain my problem but i will try,

I use Angular and I have that json in a file:

```
{
 "users": [
 {
 "gender": "male",
 "title": "mr",
 "first": "francisco",
 "last": "medina",
 "street": "2748 w dallas st",
 "city": "flowermound",
 "state": "new jersey",
 "zip": "77511",
 "email": "francisco.medina65@example.com",
 "dob": "454252284",
 "phone": "(757)-889-2571",
 "cell": "(113)-542-2123",
 "picture": {
 "large": "http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/men/22.jpg",
 "thumbnail": "http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/thumb/men/22.jpg"
 }
 },
 {
 "gender": "female",
 "title": "mrs",
 "first": "sherry",
 "last": "elliott",
 "street": "3251 brown terrace",
 "city": "wichita falls",
 "state": "washington",
 "zip": "79455",
 "email": "sherry.elliott17@example.com",
 "dob": "224238139",
 "phone": "(225)-793-2067",
 "cell": "(968)-555-1402",
 "picture": {
 "large": "http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/women/37.jpg",
 "thumbnail": "http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/thumb/women/37.jpg"
 }
 },
 {
 "gender": "male",
 "title": "mr",
 "first": "johnny",
 "last": "medina",
 "street": "1313 samaritan dr",
 "city": "redding",
 "state": "new hampshire",
 "zip": "43269",
 "email": "johnny.medina76@example.com",
 "dob": "259176886",
 "phone": "(991)-957-7139",
 "cell": "(502)-773-1487",
 "picture": {
 "large": "http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/men/90.jpg",
 "thumbnail": "http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/thumb/men/90.jpg"
 }
 }
 ]
}
```

I make http request to get the json and build a table with the results the problem is that I have to access the thumbnail picture and when i do access it it retruns me undefined, so in my opinion there is need for another http request inside that I already have but I return from the first http request three objects, so i will probably (in my opinion as I said) will need three more http requests , this is my angular code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="DemoApp">
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/i18n/angular-locale_da.js"></script>

     <style>
            table,td{
                border:1px solid black;
                border-collapse:collapse;
                padding:5px;
            }
            table tr:nth-child(even)
            {
                background-color:#ffffff;
            }
            table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table th    {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}


        </style>
</head>
<body  ng-controller="Controller as ctr">



<div class="container">



    <div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <table class="table" id="orders">
        <thead>
        <tr>   
          <th>Index</th> 
          <th>picture</th>
           <th>Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Details</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr  ng-repeat="user in users.users ">
          <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
          <td>{{user.thumbnail}}</td>
          <td>{{user.first }}</td>
          <td>{{user.last}}</td>
          <td><a href="#details">Details</a>
<!--          <td>
            <a href="#">edit</a> 
            <button ng-click ="ctrl.deleteCar(car.id)"   class="remove">X</button>
            <a href="#">delete</a>
          </td>-->
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3" style="border: thin lightblue solid; border-radius: 5px;padding: 1em;">



    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <script>
           var app = angular.module('DemoApp', []);
                                app.controller('Controller', function($http,$scope){

                              var self = this;
             $scope.users=[];         
             $scope.photoTumbnails=[];
             //var users=[];                
       $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'data.json'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) 
            {

                 $scope.users = response.data;


                   console.log("The data from the file is "+$scope.users.users)
                 console.log("The data from the file is "+$scope.users.users.thumbnail)
            }, function errorCallback(response) 
            {
                $scope.error = response.status + ": " + response.data.statusText;
            });                         



   });  


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So Can I get the image to be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<td>{{user.thumbnail}}</td>
```

to

```
<td><img ng-src="user.picture.thumbnail"/></td>
```

Comment: I changed , good advice but it is still not working , gives back the link and i need the picture associated with that link

Comment: I think it might be <td><img ng-src="user.picture.thumbnail"/></td> but I have not tested this so i am not 100%

Comment: yeah you are right .. i was edited from <td>{{}}</td> coz of that forgot to remove {{}}

Comment: <td><img ng-src="{{user.picture.thumbnail}}"/></td>   I did why that and it worked thanks guys .!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!